# Using momentjs, getting different result locally vs on Azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

he test code:

```
var c = moment().tz('America/New_York');
console.log('c.format: ' + c.format());

var b = moment([c.year(), c.month(), c.date(), c.hours(), c.minutes()]).tz('America/Chicago');
console.log("b.format: " + b.format());
```

When I run this code locally, I get:

```
c.format: 2017-07-03T16:33:42-04:00
b.format: 2017-07-03T16:33:00-05:00
```

This is what I expect (and want) to happen. Basically I just want to take a time and change the offset without changing the actual time. However, when I run that same code through my Azure hosted app, the output is this:

```
c.format: 2017-07-03T16:43:16-04:00
b.format: 2017-07-03T11:43:00-05:00
```

Both the local and Azure apps are running the same node version (8.0.0), as well as moment (2.18.1) and moment-timezone (0.5.13).

Anyone have any ideas what could be causing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) says:

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.

For your `b` variable you are creating a moment object using `c.year(), c.month(), c.date(), c.hours(), c.minutes()` as local time, so the result of converting `b` to `America/Chicago` timezone will be system dependent.

You can use [`moment.tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) to create a moment object specifying timezone (e.g. `America/New_York`), in your case, something like:

```
moment.tz([c.year(), c.month(), c.date(), c.hours(), c.minutes()], 'America/New_York')
```

Here a snippet to show live results in the different cases:

```js
// Current time in New York
var c = moment().tz('America/New_York');
console.log('c.format: ' + c.format());

// Create a local moment object for the current time in New York
var mLocal = moment([c.year(), c.month(), c.date(), c.hours(), c.minutes()]);
console.log("mLocal.format: " + mLocal.format());

// Convert local moment to America/Chicago timezone
var b = mLocal.tz('America/Chicago');
console.log("b.format: " + b.format());

// Create moment object for the current time in New York
// specifying timezone and then converting to America/Chicago timezone
var b1 = moment.tz([c.year(), c.month(), c.date(), c.hours(), c.minutes()], 'America/New_York').tz('America/Chicago');
console.log("b1.format: " + b1.format());
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Now I feel like an idiot.  I was using the moment.tz syntax elsewhere and I didn't even realize the difference.  I tried changing my timezone locally on my computer and I was still getting the correct result, so I had kind of assumed it wasn't because the server and I were on different timezones.  Guess moment is too smart for manually changing timezones!  Appreciate it.